# Extension to Pathfinding - Path of fewest turns

Tags: algorithm, methods, path-finding, a-star, heuristics

I've used [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) (and [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)) in many applications, but I'm stuck finding the path with the **fewest number of turns**, while path length is irrelevant.  I am working with an up-down-left-right grid, no diagonals.

A* defines `Cost = DistanceFromStart + Heuristic(`[`Manhattan`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)`)`, and I've tried to extend it by adding a `numTurns` cost. This works perfectly until I get to a case like this:

`|  0  0  0  0  0  *  0  0`  
`|  0  0  1' 2' +  0  0  E`  
`|  0  0  S  1  2  *  0  0`  
`|  0  0  0  0  0  *  0  0`  
`|  0  0  0  0  0  *  0  0`     (`*`=wall, `0`=empty, `S`=start, `E`=end)

You will find that the path `S->1->2->+` will give the same cost as `s->1'->2'->+`. They both have one turn so far, same distance from `S`, and same Manhattan.  However from the `+`, if we took the prime `'` route, we don't have to turn. But if we took the `1 2` route, we have to turn right (`+1` cost). Thus, even though we may arrive there first with `1 2`, it is **not** the path of least turns.

I have tried adjustments such as letting multiple of the same square be in the priority queue at once such that they both get a chance (if their values are minimal in the heap) and other "hacky" solutions, but keep getting cases that aren't covered. Is there an intuitive way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'm facing the same problem and haven't find a proper solution yet.

Comment: Here's an academic paper that provides an algorithm.
http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1003/1003.3536.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Create a new distance matrix. For locations i and j, if they are in a straight line (no turns), set distance(i,j)=1. For the rest of the elements set to infinity. Now run any shortest distance algorithm over it.

Comment: Am i correct in assuming this will use O(n^3) many elements of the distance graph? Every row of the initial matrix has n elements, for each of which (ignoring duplicates) you'll have to calculate n distances. There are n rows in the matrix. Analogously this goes for columns as well but addition doesn't matter in O-notation anyway. Using Dijsktra's algorithm with priority queues, this would take O(n^3 log n) time where n is the size of a row/column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to incorporate a 'direction' into your state. When you arrive at '+' from 1->2->+ you are facing 'up', and when you arrive at '+' from 1'->2'->+ you are facing 'right'.

You can then incorporate the cost of changing direction into your 'cost-to-go'. That is, the cost of travelling from one state to the other. Now, going 1->2->+, when estimating a move to the right, will factor in the cost of changing direction, while 1'->2'->+ will not.

When you get to the 'generate children' phase of your A*, you are probably only incrementing the 'cost-so-far' by 1, the number of gridcells it took to move to a neighbor. You also need to add 1 if the neighbor's direction to your current position is != to your current direction.

For the start, you can use some special facing direction like OMNIDIRECTIONAL, so that moving to any square from the start position doesn't incur a cost.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, and I await your further explaination. I do have directions on my BoardSquares, such that if my last movement was "right", and I go right again, numTurns stays the same. But, if I were to go left, down, or up, numTurns would iterate and the curDirection would change to its respective value. The problem is, unless im misunderstanding your solution, that if the 1 2 path arrives at + first, and + is picked, + is locked into place (closed list). Any further calculation from then will not know about the 1'2' path that never reached it (regardless of same cost)

Comment: So even though turning right on 1 2 incurs a cost, and 1' 2' does not, it is not + who realizes this, it is the square to the right of +. By the time we get there, I think its too late to go back (unless we allow multiple of the same square with different heritages in the pqueue). Thanks again for taking the time to look at this with me!

Comment: The '+' state arrived at from 1->2->+ is NOT the same '+' state as arrived at from 1'->2'->+. When you compare two states, comparing only their x,y coordinates is not enough, you must also compare the direction you are facing at those coordinates.

This way, both '+' states can be added to the list, but at different costs.

Comment: I wish I could vote you up, but I need to ask more questions I guess. Your solution is the same as mine, actually. It turns out it wasn't working due to the various ways I was calling it en masse. You see, the board has nearly 100 tiles, so I call the pathfinding algorithm 50 times at minimum. I was forgetting to reset the tiles in various ways, I wasn't clearing my various data structures, etc. Therefore, the errors seemed to be coming from the pathfinding, but it was actually its bugged input. It seems to be working now (fingers crossed), and Im working on finishing the UI.

Comment: I want to thank you again for your time. You arrived at that algorithm much faster than I did, so I wish I had asked days ago. But it's good for the brain I suppose! This is interesting stuff, and I love automation, so its fun to make a game solver. I wish you the best!

Comment: @user2045279: It's my pleasure. I hope after you find your final solution, you edit your post with it so people in the future can find it! And perhaps one day you can answer other people's questions!

Comment: Certainly, once I do the finishing touches and perform some extensive testing I'll be sure to post the algorithm. It's funny how randomized things can really throw you off in debugging. For instance, the board im solving is always a random series of tiles with id's ranging from 1 to 24. Based on what the board was, various bugs can crop up that wouldn't for another permuation of tiles. The only way to solidify my results beyond further code analysis is testing on many boards! For full automation, I can just have it run for a couple hours and test thousands of boards.